# Entropy Optimal Quick Sort

Tags: c++, algorithm, sorting, c++11, quicksort

I was doing an exercise for sorting in my Algorithms class where we are required to implement various sorting algorithms and test them against the inputs provided by our professor.

I have the following implementation for quick-sort which is entropy optimal meaning it may be faster than the NlogN bound when a large sequence of elements are equal. The implementation I have done can be found below this post (removed the pastebin link as suggested in the comments)

On running it I found out that it is slower than the std::sort algorithm (I do understand that this is just a difference in the constant for the NlogN) bounds, but as a result I miss the time limits for large input sequences.

Also when the input size is 1000000, std::sort is able to sort but my algorithm gives me a segmentation fault. Can someone please take a look at this and let me know if I am doing something wrong. Thanks in advance.

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <random>
#include <utility>

struct Sort {
public:
        enum class SortAlg { selection = 0, insertion, shell, merge, mergeBU, quick, heap };
        template <typename T, int N>
        static void sort(T (&arr) [N], SortAlg alg) {
                SortArray<T,N> sortM (arr);
                switch (alg) {
                        case SortAlg::quick:
                                sortM.quicksort(); break;
                        default:
                                sortM.quicksort();
                };
        }
private:
        template <typename T, int N>
        class SortArray {
        public:
                SortArray(T (&a) [N]) : arr(a) {}
                void quicksort();
        private:
                void qsort(int lo, int hi);
                std::pair<int, int> partition(int lo, int hi);
                T (&arr) [N];
        };
};


template <typename T, int N>
void Sort::SortArray<T, N>::quicksort(){
        qsort(0, N-1);
}

template <typename T, int N>
void Sort::SortArray<T, N>::qsort(int lo, int hi){
if (lo >= hi) return;
        std::pair<int, int> part = partition(lo, hi);
        qsort(lo, part.first);
        qsort (part.second, hi);
}

//This partitions the algorithm into 3 ranges
//1st range - elements less than the partition element
//2nd range - elements equal to the partition element
//3rd range - elements greater than the partition element
//it returns a pair (a,b) where[a+1, b-1] represents the
//equal range which will be left out of subsequent sorts and
//the next set of sorting will be on [lo,a] and [b,hi]
template <typename T, int N>
std::pair<int, int> Sort::SortArray<T, N>::partition(int lo, int hi){
        static int count = 0;
        std::random_device rd;
        std::mt19937_64 gen(rd());
        std::uniform_int_distribution<int> dis;
        int elem = lo + (dis(gen) % (hi-lo+1)); //position of element around which paritioning happens
        using std::swap;
        swap(arr[lo], arr[elem]);
        int val = arr[lo];
        //after the while loop below completes
        //the range of elements [lo, eqind1-1] and  [eqind2+1, hi] will all be equal to arr[lo]
        //the range of elements [eqind1, gt] will all be less than arr[lo]
        //the range of elements [lt, eqind2] will all be greated than arr[lo]
        int lt = lo+1, gt = hi, eqind1 = lo, eqind2 = hi;
        while (true){
                while(lt <= gt && arr[lt] <= val) {
                        if (arr[lt] == val){
                                if(lt == eqind1 + 1)
                                        ++eqind1;
                                else
                                        swap(arr[lt], arr[++eqind1]);
                        }
                        ++lt;
                }
                while(gt >= lt && arr[gt] >= val) {
                        if(arr[gt] == val){
                                if(gt == eqind2)
                                        --eqind2;
                                else
                                        swap(arr[gt], arr[eqind2--]);
                        }
                        --gt;
                };
                if(lt >= gt) break;
                swap(arr[lt], arr[gt]); ++lt; --gt;
        };
        swap(arr[lo], arr[gt]);
        if (eqind1!=lo){
                    //there are some elements equal to arr[lo] in the first eqind1-1 places
                    //move the elements which are less than arr[lo] to the beginning
                for (int i = 1; i<lt-eqind1; i++)
                        arr[lo+i] = arr[lo + eqind1+i];
        }
        if (eqind2!=hi){
                    //there are some elements which are equal to arr[lo] in the last eqind2-1 places
                    //move the elements which are greater than arr[lo] towards the end of the array
                for(int i = hi; i>gt; i--)
                        arr[i] = arr[i-hi+eqind2];
        }    
        //calculate the number of elements equal to arr[lo] and fill them up in between
        //the elements less than and greater than arr[lo]
        int numequals = eqind1 - lo + hi - eqind2 + 1;
        if(numequals != 1){
                for(int i = 0; i < numequals; i++)
                        arr[lo+lt-eqind1+i-1] = val;
        }
        //calculate the range of elements that are less than and greater than arr[lo]
        //and return them back to qsort
        int lorange = lo + lt-eqind1-2;
        int hirange = lo + lt - eqind1 - 1 + numequals;
        return {lorange, hirange};
}

int main() {
        std::random_device rd;
        std::mt19937_64 gen(rd());
        std::uniform_int_distribution<int> dis;
        constexpr int size = 100000;
        int arr[size], arr1[size];
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++){
                arr[i] = dis(gen)%9;
                arr1[i] = arr[i];;  
        }
        std::sort(std::begin(arr1), std::end(arr1));
        std::cout << "Standard sort finished" << std::endl;
        Sort::sort(arr, Sort::SortAlg::quick);
        std::cout << "Custom sort finished" << std::endl;
        int i =0;
        int countDiffer = 0;
        for (; i <size; ++i){
                if (arr[i] != arr1[i]){
                        countDiffer++;
                }
        }
        if (i == size) std::cout << "Sorted" << std::endl;
        else std::cout << "Not sorted and differ in " << countDiffer
                       << " places" << std::endl;   
}
```

Comment: you are using an array of 1.000.000 ints (each 4 byte) which is asking for a large space (4GB) of continious memory - probably allocation fails. try a `std::deque` perhaps?

Comment: @Alex: 4MB? Probably a bug in the implementation that keeps recursing if the values are equqal?

Comment: Hi Alex, it is not a problem with allocation because if it were so then even the call to std::sort would have failed...the stack size on the machine where i am running it is 8 MB which should be more than enough....it is surely a problem with my implementation which is where i need you guys' help...

Comment: the other weird thing I noticed is that you initialize an RNG with every call of partition (can also be expensive).

Comment: Creating a new random number generator on each `partition` is unnecessary, and using `%` destroys the uniformity. Use `uniform_int_distribution<int> dis(lo, hi); int elem = dis(gen);` (And only create one RNG.)

Comment: Perfect .... thanks a lot Alex....that solved the problem...i moved the RNG code out of the partition function (a horrible mistake) and now the code works for a million elements as well....thank you so much....if u can post this as an answer, i will accept it....thanks a ton...u saved me a lot of headache...

Comment: thanks molbdnilo....i will change that as well...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is two problems with the code.

A) You are creating a stack allocated array that might be large. Once the stacksize overflows the next page might be anything from unmapped to random heap memory.

B) The other weird thing I noticed is that you initialize an RNG with every call of partition (can also be expensive) which wastes stack space for every partition point.

Comment: Thanks...moving the RNG out resolved both the problems i.e. the stack overflowing and the running time being slower than std::sort algorithm by a significant margin...

Comment: You have also template bloat in there

Comment: We will be running this code on only 3 sets of inputs i.e int arrays (small, medium and large)...so there will be 3 instances generated for each of the member functions which is something i can live with...since this is an algorithms class, not much importance is being given to writing production safe code....moreover the template was provided by the professor and we are just extending it

Answer (score 2):

You have two different problems, that should really warrant two different questions. I will however answer one for you.

<sub>Oh, and in the future please don't have links to code, what if that link goes dead? Then your question will be useless.</sub>

---

The problem with the crash is that just about all compilers place local variables (including arrays) on the stack, and the stack is limited. On Windows, for example, the default stack for a process is only a single megabyte.

With two such arrays, each of a 1000000 entries each, you will have ***eight megabytes*** (which happens to be the default stack-size for Linux processes), plus of course space for the function call stack frames and all the other local variables and arguments etc. This is beyond (or *way* beyond) the available stack, and you will have *undefined behavior* and a probable crash.

Comment: Thanks Joachim ... i understand that ... but the problem is that i get a segmentation fault even if i just allocate one array of 1000000 entries and call my sorting algorithm on it.....it works however for arrays lesser 100000 elements....i did some checking to see the algorithm running time for test cases where element size doubles and found out that the algorithm is NlgN....but it is still slower than the std::sort algorithm...is there anything else that i can do to improve the speed....for now we can ignore the segmentation fault issue...

Comment: @user3493289 It works even for e.g. 999999 elements? I doubt that. What you *should* do is tell us if you're on Windows, Linux, OSX or some other OS, because then we can tell what the stack size is, and then we can tell you the max size your arrays can be.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft's std::sort uses introsort. Wiki link:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Introsort

Introsort switches from quicksort to heapsort if the nesting reaches some limit, primarily for performance reasons, since an indicator that quicksort is going to be slow is excessive nesting, but it also has the side benefit of preventing excessive nesting from running a thread out of stack space.